# Since Chrome version 75 upgrade I'm getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Immediately following the Chrome upgrade a site I connected to beforehand is now giving me

> ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE

.  When I tried with FireFox I received error

> SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Opera works fine.  When I connect with `openssl s_client -connect dev.mysite.com:443 -debug`, the session establishes and I receive the cert.  I host the site using NGINX 1.14 using OpenSSL 1.1.1.

Comment: What does https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning the site with `nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 dev.mysite.com` gave me a warning:

> Key exchange (dh 2048) of lower strength than certificate key

The site's RSA key is 4096, but the dhparam.pem file only 2048.  After I generated a new dhparam file with `openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096`, all the browsers work again.